# HTML id block replacement

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I'm learning cshtml/js and I'm not quite sure how to replace blocks of text. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

       <p id = "Jonny">Jonny the giant </p>
       <p> hi there <b id ="mytext"> dood! </b></p>

    <script>
        function Replace() {
            y = document.getElementById("mytext");
            y.innerHTML = "new string";             @* what I want to do -->  document.getElementById("Jonny");*@
        }
    </script>

    <button
        type = "button" onclick = "Replace()" > 'MAGIC SWAP'
    </button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to replace the chunk of text with another chunk of text that I have identified with and id name

Comment: What's the problem with writing `y.innerHTML = document.getElementById('Johnny').innerHTML`?

Comment: you should tidy up your html. you're mixing up the contents of `head` and `body`. syntactically the fragment is not conformant to the specs.

Comment: That works! but I do not understand why innerHTML is at the end.

Comment: `document.getElementById('Johnny')` gets the internal data structure corresponding to the `b[id=mytext]` element, the `innerHTML` method generates the lexical representation of its content in as html.

Comment: You need to understand that Razor is executed on the server while HTML, JavaScript and CSS is executed on the client (browser). You want to replace a chunk of text in Razor or in HTML?

Comment: @Alerty never though about that. I was only wondering how to do it in HTML but it would be nice to know how to do it in Razor as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you're after.
`document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Jonny").innerHTML;`

Here's a cleaned up version of your `HTML`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script>
  function Replace() {
    document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Jonny").innerHTML;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="Jonny">Jonny the giant</p>
  <p>Hi there <b id="mytext"> dood! </b></p>

  <button type="button" onclick="Replace()">MAGIC SWAP</button>
</body>
</html>
```